# using seq_along() to handle the empty case

Tags: r, seq, is-empty

I read that using `seq_along()` allows to handle the empty case much better, but this concept is not so clear in my mind.

For example, I have this data frame:

```
df
            a            b          c          d
1   1.2767671  0.133558438  1.5582137  0.6049921
2  -1.2133819 -0.595845408 -0.9492494 -0.9633872
3   0.4512179  0.425949910  0.1529301 -0.3012190
4   1.4945791  0.211932487 -1.2051334  0.1218442
5   2.0102918  0.135363711  0.2808456  1.1293810
6   1.0827021  0.290615747  2.5339719 -0.3265962
7  -0.1107592 -2.762735937 -0.2428827 -0.3340126
8   0.3439831  0.323193841  0.9623515 -0.1099747
9   0.3794022 -1.306189542  0.6185657  0.5889456
10  1.2966537 -0.004927108 -1.3796625 -1.1577800
```

Considering these three different code snippets:

```
# Case 1
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    print(median(df[[i]]))
}

# Case 2
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    print(median(df[[i]]))
}

# Case 3
for(i in df) print(median(i))
```

What is the difference between these different procedures when a full `data.frame` exists or in the presence of an empty `data.frame`?

Comment: Why don't you see for yourself using `df <- data.frame()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the condition that `df <- data.frame()`, we have:

**Case 1** falling victim to...

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

while **Case 2 and 3** are *not* triggered.

In essence, the error in **Case 1** is due to `ncol(df)` being `0`. This leads the sequence `1:ncol(df)` to be `1:0`, which creates the vector `c(1,0)`. In this case, the `for` loop tries to access the first element of the vector `1`, which tries to access column 1 does *not* exist. Hence, the subset is found to be out of bounds.

Meanwhile, in **Case 2 and 3** the `for` loop is never executed since there are no elements to process within their respective collections since the vectors are *empty*. Principally, this means that they have length of `0`.

As this question specifically relates to what the heck is happening to `seq_along()`, let's take a traditional `seq_along` example by constructing a full vector `a` and seeing the results:

```
set.seed(111)
a <- runif(5)
seq_along(a)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

In essence, for each element of the vector `a`, there is a corresponding index that was created by `seq_along` to be accessed.

If we apply `seq_along` now to the empty `df` in the above case, we get:

```
seq_along(df)
# integer(0)
```

Thus, what was created was a zero length vector. Its mighty hard to move along a zero length vector.

Ergo, the **Case 1** *poorly protects* the against the **empty case**.

Now, under the traditional assumption, that is there is some data within the `data.frame`, which is a very *bad* assumption for any kind of developer to make...

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(40), 4))
```

All *three* cases would be operating as expected. That is, you would receive a median per column of the `data.frame`.

```
[1] -0.5555419
[1] -0.4941011
[1] -0.4656169
[1] -0.605349
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out in your answer that `1:ncol(df)` for an empty data frame is the same as `1:0` which outputs the two element vector `c(0, 1)` rather than an empty vector as with he other two examples.